# Spring boot application as dependency in another gradle project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

How can i add a spring boot built using gradle as a dependecy to another spring boot application ?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/core_dependency_management.html)? If so, which part is unclear?

Comment: yes i did. but it does not answer my question.

Comment: So are you unsure how to add a dependency in general (either a Maven dependency or a project dependency), or is your question about the use of "fat jars" as dependencies? In either case, I think your question will be better with some more context.

Comment: My question is about adding a spring boot application as dependency. I dont know if i can add a fat jar as-is as a  dependency in maven/gradle